# How use get method in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new to redux can anyone tell me how to use redux in GET method, can any one explain With example, it will be more helpful for me.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking about here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a GET method another application in Redux, you must to do this:

First define the action:

action/index.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const FETCH_DATA = 'FETCH_DATA';

const ROOT_URL = 'http://host:port';

export function fetchData(){
    const request = axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/condition_type`)
    return {
        type: FETCH_DATA,
        payload: request
    }
}
```

reducer/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import ConditionReducer from './reducer_data';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    data: DataReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

reducer/reducer_data.js

```
import {FETCH_DATA} from '../actions/index';

export default function(state = [], action){

    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_DATA:
            return action.payload.data
            break;
        default:
            return state;

    }
}
```

components/some_component.js

```
import React ,{Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {fetchData} from '../../actions/index';

class DataIndex extends Component {
    componentWillMount(){
        this.props.fetchData();
    }

    render (){
        return(
            <div>
            Do what you want with the information
            {this.props.data}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {data: state.data};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchData})(DataIndex);
```